# XSLT group by value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML document

```
<Contracts>   
    <Contract>
        <F1>key1</F1>
        <F2>2345</F2>
        <F3>val</F3>
        <F4>dal</F4>
    </Contract>
    <Contract>
        <F1>key1</F1>
        <F2>34562</F2>
        <F3>val</F3>
        <F4>dal</F4>
    </Contract>
    <Contract>
        <F1>key2</F1>
        <F2>416235</F2>
        <F3>val</F3>
        <F4>sal</F4>
    </Contract> 
    <Contract>
        <F1>key2</F1>
        <F2>416235</F2>
        <F3>val</F3>
        <F4>sal</F4>
    </Contract> 
    <Contract>
        <F1>key2</F1>
        <F2>41575</F2>
        <F3>val</F3>
        <F4>bal</F4>
    </Contract>
</Contracts>
```

I need group these contracts by `Contracts/Contract/F1` (key1, key2) to get this result:

```
<Contracts>
    <Set>
        <Contract>
            <F1>key1</F1>
            <F2>2345</F2>
            <F3>val</F3>
            <F4>dal</F4>
        </Contract>
        <Contract>
            <F1>key1</F1>
            <F2>34562</F2>
            <F3>val</F3>
            <F4>dal</F4>
        </Contract>
    <Set>
    <Set>
        <Contract>
            <F1>key2</F1>
            <F2>416235</F2>
            <F3>val</F3>
            <F4>sal</F4>
        </Contract> 
        <Contract>
            <F1>key2</F1>
            <F2>416235</F2>
            <F3>val</F3>
            <F4>sal</F4>
        </Contract> 
        <Contract>
            <F1>key2</F1>
            <F2>416235</F2>
            <F3>val</F3>
            <F4>sal</F4>
        </Contract>
   </Set>
</Contracts>
```

How can I do it with XSLT ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an XSL key and Muenchian grouping.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:key name="kContract" match="Contract" use="F1" />

  <xsl:template match="Contracts">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="
        Contract[
          generate-id() = generate-id(key('kContract', F1)[1])
        ]
      ">
        <Set>
          <xsl:copy-of select="key('kContract', F1)" />
        </Set>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This stylesheet produces exactly the output you want.

Comment: in my XSLT I have the namespace xmlns="http://www.name.com" and it appears in Set tag : <Set xmlns="http://www.name.com">. And addition Contract tags have the empty namespace <Contract xmlns=""> How can I delete it ?

Comment: @Wachburn: Well, just remove the namespace from your XSLT if you don't need it.

Comment: but I need it, why they appear there?

Comment: @Wachburn: This namespace isn't in the XML document you have provided. Either edit your question and provide the namespace or, **better**, ask a new question.

Answer (score 4):

**I. XSLT 1.0 solution** (Muenchian grouping, no `xsl:for-each`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kContrByF1" match="Contract" use="F1"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "Contract[not(generate-id()
               =
                generate-id(key('kContrByF1', F1)[1])
                )
            ]"/>

 <xsl:template match="Contract">
  <Contract>
   <Set>
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('kContrByF1', F1)"/>
   </Set>
  </Contract>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Contracts>
    <Contract>
        <F1>key1</F1>
        <F2>2345</F2>
        <F3>val</F3>
        <F4>dal</F4>
    </Contract>
    <Contract>
        <F1>key1</F1>
        <F2>34562</F2>
        <F3>val</F3>
        <F4>dal</F4>
    </Contract>
    <Contract>
        <F1>key2</F1>
        <F2>416235</F2>
        <F3>val</F3>
        <F4>sal</F4>
    </Contract>
    <Contract>
        <F1>key2</F1>
        <F2>416235</F2>
        <F3>val</F3>
        <F4>sal</F4>
    </Contract>
    <Contract>
        <F1>key2</F1>
        <F2>41575</F2>
        <F3>val</F3>
        <F4>bal</F4>
    </Contract>
</Contracts>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Contracts>
   <Contract>
      <Set>
         <Contract>
            <F1>key1</F1>
            <F2>2345</F2>
            <F3>val</F3>
            <F4>dal</F4>
         </Contract>
         <Contract>
            <F1>key1</F1>
            <F2>34562</F2>
            <F3>val</F3>
            <F4>dal</F4>
         </Contract>
      </Set>
   </Contract>
   <Contract>
      <Set>
         <Contract>
            <F1>key2</F1>
            <F2>416235</F2>
            <F3>val</F3>
            <F4>sal</F4>
         </Contract>
         <Contract>
            <F1>key2</F1>
            <F2>416235</F2>
            <F3>val</F3>
            <F4>sal</F4>
         </Contract>
         <Contract>
            <F1>key2</F1>
            <F2>41575</F2>
            <F3>val</F3>
            <F4>bal</F4>
         </Contract>
      </Set>
   </Contract>
</Contracts>
```

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <Contracts>
       <xsl:for-each-group select="Contract" group-by="F1">
         <Contract>
          <Set>
            <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"/>
          </Set>
         </Contract>
       </xsl:for-each-group>
     </Contracts>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Again, when this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above) the same correct result is produced.**

Do note:

1. The use of the `xsl:for-each-group` instruction.
2. The use of the `current-group()` function.

Comment: @Tomalak: Thanks. I also think promoting non-xsl-for-each XSLT 1.0 code is something our readers need -- to know that they can think completely in non-procedural terms. Of course, your answer is good and precise and by no means am I hinting that it has any shortcomings :)

Comment: I usually do this. In most of my answers where this is an issue I've actively discouraged the use of `<for-each>` or at least passively rewrote the code to push-style — this time I wanted to keep my answer short.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes. This is exactly how I perceive your answer.